# Reading image from sdcard returning null opencv

Tags: android, opencv

i am trying to read images from SDCARD using c++ opencv method, but its returning no image,

stich.cpp
    Mat img = imread("/storage/emulated/0/panoTmpImage/im" + id + ".jpeg");

i try this path too but its not working `/storage/sdcard0/panoTmpImages/im"+id+".jpeg"`

**Edit**
this method work perfectly , i dont know why imread is not reading iamges.thanks for help
        Mat img4 = cvLoadImage("/storage/sdcard0/panoTmpImage/im3.jpeg",1);

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should try it this way:

```
Mat img = imread(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/panoTmpImage/im" + id + ".jpeg");
```

Add this to your android manifest also:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: ok, you can still use this code, but encase it like so:
Mat img = imread(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +"/panoTmpImage/im" + id + ".jpeg");

Comment: @sara have you tried this path name? "/system/media/sdcard/panoTmpImages/im"+id+".jpeg" - possible sdcard0?

Comment: Or maybe "/mnt/sdcard/...rest of path"

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add a permission in your androidManifest.xml to read from external storage.